# Init an array using contents of spans

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no Idea how to init my banner array with the text inside my spans. Do you have any Idea? Better to use javascript or JQuery?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;

    function fun() {
        var banner = new Array();
        //How to init array here from inner text of spans?
        i++;
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "slide/" + banner[i] + ".jpg";
        if (i == 3) //here 2 is number of images i want to display in the slide show
        {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    setInterval("fun()", 4000);
</script>

<div class="imagesContainer" style="display:none;">
        <span>
            73defe4b-9819-4e12-b351-3813686e0c83.gif
        </span>
        <span>
            4c2ed116-500d-42ad-8aa5-983bf214d5d3.png
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be using [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) for this instead of static text, otherwise users who visit your site without JavaScript enabled will just see a load of jibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var i = 1;

function fun() {
    var banner = $('.imagesContainer span').map(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text())
    }).get();
    //How to init array here from inner text of spans?
    i++;
    document.getElementById("img1").src = "slide/" + banner[i] + ".jpg";
    if (i == 3) //here 2 is number of images i want to display in the slide show
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
setInterval("fun()", 4000);
```

---

```
jQuery(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var banner = $('.imagesContainer span').map(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text())
    }).get();

    function fun() {
        //How to init array here from inner text of spans?
        i++;
        if (i == banner.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        $('#img1').attr('src', '//placehold.it/128/' + banner[i])
    }
    setInterval(fun, 1000);
})
```

PoC: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4H33L/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it using jQuery:

```
var banner = [];
$('.imagesContainer span').each(function() {
  banner.push($(this).text());
});
// you can now use the banner array here
```